# How to output as decimals when already using FLOOR to get a result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello So i have been struggling and i tried a few things to try and make it work but I think im lacking some syntax knowledge perhaps.

So what is confusing for me is that i'm using AS to get my results and then I need to convert that result into decimals. I am not advanced enough to figure this out and most of the examples I found overly complicated for my application of these functions. I would appreciate any tip or link in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: What is an example current output, and what do you want it to output? If you want it to 2dp then why are you `floor`ing the division?

Comment: I never done in any other way before :s I am very new to mysql.

Comment: Why? A number is no different whether you display it as 4 or 4.00

Comment: So, FLOOR rounds the result down to an int. So you'll always get a whole number.

Comment: `FLOOR` by definition returns an integer. If you need decimal places, then simply remove it from your query.

Comment: If i divide my kills with the deaths say i got 1 kill and 3 deaths that gives me 0.33 KDR I would like to be able to display that instead of just 0.

EDIT: Ok sweet i removed the floor, and it shows all of the results now. Thank you guys!

Comment: Well then don't use `FLOOR`!

Comment: Yeah, so remove the FLOOR call, that should stop the rounding.

Comment: Why would you use LEFT on a decimal?

Comment: But what if their high-score is > 9999? then you'd just be truncating data.

Comment: @REDRUM you can use `Truncate` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't build a schema to test this, but I think you are making things too complicated:

```
SELECT
    highscores.name,
    CAST(highscores.kills / highscores.deaths AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS kdr
FROM
    hsdb.highscores 
ORDER BY
    kdr DESC LIMIT 10
```

highscores.deaths = 0 will be a case you have to deal with.

Comment: what do you mean by this ?
` highscores.deaths = 0 will be a case you have to deal with. `

Comment: Dividing by zero will cause an error. Mathematically, it's a special form of infinity, and computers hate infinity.

Comment: Yes, something like that. You might want to return 1, to put that user at the top of the list.

Comment: Test that case and work on it, and if you need help, ask another question. Someone will be happy to help.

Comment: But no, I don't think your first try will work. You need to test for highscores.deaths = 0 and not do the query if it is.

Comment: @ jerry Gotcha Thanks alot !

Comment: @jerry did you ever execute “select 1/0” on MySQL? It will not error it will return NULL, i believe MySQL, MariaDB and SQLite are the only databases i know off that will not error when dividing by 0

Comment: As long as MySQL doesn't explode on the division, that looks like a good solution. But you might want to coalesce to 1 rather than 0 so people with no deaths are at the top of the list.

Comment: @REDRUM if i was you i would add a “WHERE CAST(highscores.kills / highscores.deaths AS DECIMAL (10,2)) IS NOT NULL” instead to filter out the possible division by 0 values which become NULL then you dont have to use coalesce and you know for a fact you are sorting and limitting on a valid kill death ratio calculation

Comment: @RaymondNijland but you want the ratio of people with no deaths to be 1, rather than be ignored.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Will give it a try now :)

Comment: While you try it, you can simplify to `WHERE highscores.kills / highscores.deaths IS NOT NULL.

Comment: or, highscores.deaths > 0

Comment: @REDRUM that was not what i or Jerry meant to say and not wierd that that does not work